# How to get url for static image file in Magento 2's javascript files?

Tags: magento2

I need to get a URL for an image stored in my theme (`app/design/frontend/MyVendor/MyTheme/web/images/image.png`) from a javascript file (`payment.js`).

In PHP I can do it like this:

```
<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/image.png') ?>
```

How can I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: Formatting, removed irrelevant tags

Comment: genuine question, don't know why it is downvoted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it by adding variable to window from *.phtml file:

```
<script>
    window.imgpath = '<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/image.png') ?>';
</script>
```

and reading that variable from window in *.js:

```
function someFunction() {
    var imgPath = window.imgpath;
}
```

Actually, in Magento core files I saw examples of such things.

Answer (score 15):

In JavaScript it's available with `require.toUrl('images/image.png')`.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do it is:

.phtml file

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Module/js/example":"<?php echo "test" ?>"
        }
    }        
</script>
```

.js file

```
define([], function () {
    var mageJsComponent = function(config)
    {
        console.log(config);
    };

    return mageJsComponent;
});
```

Doc: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html